# Rotating scope in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-styles

Can't able to rotate scope with external image (fig.pdf).

```
\begin{scope} [rotate=30]
    \node (scope6) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{/tmp/fig1}}; 
    \node at (0,0) [rotate=0,color=black] {Text};
 \end{scope}
```

Please help me to rotate this external image fig1.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the `[transform shape]` option when creating the node.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope} [rotate=30]
    \node [transform shape](scope6) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{example-image}}; 
    \node at (0,0) [rotate=0,color=black] {Text};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works fine.  I don't know why this "[transform shape]", it should rotate as we put rotate for scope.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

[image]

For this `scope` doesn't work. You can simply do the following:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               multi,
               tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
    \node[rotate=30,draw=red,very thick] (scope6) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
    \node [font=\bfseries\Huge,text=white] {Text};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

I add border to node that you can see, how the node is aligned with image inside it.