# How can I make a dog bone contour with the imaginary axis cut out in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Theres already one post on this stack exchange regarding a dog bone contour, but I'm trying to draw one that has the positive imaginary axis cut out as well as the dog bone. I really don't get how to use tikz, at all so I'm not really sure how to change the code to make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also this is the post regarding the other dog bone contour:
[post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298795/draw-the-dogbone-contour-for-complex-integral)

Comment: Hi Christopher and Welcome to TSE. If you just want a quick rotation of some drawing, you may use `\begin{scope}[rotate=90] <some drawing> \end{scope}` as presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310398/rotating-scope-in-tikz).

Comment: I'm not trying to rotate it, I'm trying to connect the dogbone to the rest of the circle via a gap that encloses the positive imaginary axis. So if you walked along the path and started at \theta=0 and at the radius of the circle you'd travel around the circle until just before the imaginary axis, then you would travel down a line to the dogbone, around the dogbone, back up on the other side of the imaginary axis then trace out the rest of the circle

Comment: Please, be so kind and show as what you try so far and provide a sketch, what you like to draw.